# Can epsilon be a big positive number?

Tags: real-analysis, soft-question

This is a bit of a soft question, but I was just wondering, in the real analysis epsilon-delta definitions of limits and continuity, can epsilon be a very big positive number, like a googol, or a googolplex? And if it can be, why don't textbooks restrict epsilon to be a small positive real number, like, "For any positive epsilon less than $1$..."?

Comment: In the usual arguments, $\epsilon$ can be any positive real number, though only the case where $\epsilon$ tends to $0$ is interesting.  Beyond that, I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: The point is that we have a certain inequality for all $\epsilon$. If I can arrange it for $\epsilon$ I can arrange it for any $\epsilon'>\epsilon$, so the focus (especially intuitively) is on the small numbers, mathematically there is no loss in saying "suppose $0<\epsilon<1$" (which, by the way, people *do* do for convenience sometimes)

Comment: The technical definition of limit (or most other definitions that involve $\epsilon$) say that $\epsilon$ is an arbitrary number $\epsilon > 0$ that might be as big as a googol.  But usually the given statement is easy to prove for very large $\epsilon$. If you have a theorem that says something like "suppose $0 < \epsilon < 1$" that's kind-of an invitation for you to prove separately the case $\epsilon \geq 1$ (with the implication that it's easy and not necessary for the author to write explicitly.)

Comment: Alternatively, you can prove as an exercise that the definition of limit (or what have you) is equivalent to the definition that only requires it to be shown for $0 < \epsilon < 1$, or indeed $ 0 < \epsilon < \epsilon'$ for any fixed $\epsilon' > 0$.

Comment: If an inequality like $|F(x)|<\epsilon $ is satisfied for small epsilon, then it will be satisfied for large epsilon.

Comment: @JairTaylor Yes, please prove it as an exercise here.

Comment: A googolplex is not a very big number; almost all numbers are much, much bigger.

Comment: The proof of this exercise is a one line application of the transitive law of inequality.

Comment: @user14111 This can also be said about Grahams number or TREE(3). In this context , it is enough to use googolplex to refute that $\epsilon$ must be "small" although in fact it can be any real number no matter how large.